# What is an alternative tool for MSpec integration with Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, resharper, mspec

I recently finished a C# project and wrote tests with MSpec using Machine.Fakes. I have been using the command line runner. It would be more comfortable to see the test results/runs inside Visual Studio. But, ReSharper is outside of my budget. Is there an attractive alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I highly recommend getting ReSharper. It's much more than just a test runner. In my experience, working without ReSharper is less productive.

There are test runners for several commercial products available:

- [TestDriven.Net](http://testdriven.net/)
- [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)
- [CodeRush](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/)
- [JustCode](http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode.aspx)

TestDriven.Net should be cheaper than ReSharper, but it is only a test runner. The other products are similar to what ReSharper provides, but I haven't worked with them.

There are also continuous test runners for Visual Studio:

- [MightyMoose](http://continuoustests.com)
- [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/)

Both are free as of today.

There's also [Gallio](http://www.gallio.org/), which might offer integration into VS.

As a last option, you can set up MSpec's exe runner as an external tool to see test run output in the Output window.

For VS 2012 we'll probably have a runner that integrates without the need for extra tools.

Comment: TestDriven.NET is not cheaper than Resharper.  In fact, for a single language solution, Resharper is actually cheaper, AND ReSharper provides a built in test runner that is pretty decent.  I'm quite surprised that TestDriven.NET is so costly as I'm not sure why anyone would purchase the license.

Comment: +1 On a side note, MightyMoose, and NCrunch look awesome and I think I will be trying them this weekend.  Thanks for the reference.